# Facebook like and comment not working on Android webview

Tags: android-studio, android-webview

I have tried webview with Android studio and FB share and other social media share buttons are working fine. But FB direct like and comment button on my website is not working. When I press like button I can see white screen with left top screen number "1". Please kindly help me.

## MainActivity.Java

```
package com.example.neermaicom;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

import static android.content.Intent.*;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private WebView webView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

getSupportActionBar().hide();
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

webView = findViewById(R.id.webview);
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
    if (url == null || url.startsWith("http://") || url.startsWith("https://")) return false;

    try {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
        view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
        return true;
    } catch (Exception e) {

        return true;
    }
}
});
webView.loadUrl("http://www.neermai.com");

WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
}

//This method require to use back button if want to go previous web page

 @Override
 public void onBackPressed() {

 if(webView.canGoBack()){
    webView.goBack();
 }else {
    super.onBackPressed();
 }
 }
```

### Activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<WebView
android:id="@+id/webview"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Can you post some code that you've tried? It's hard to say what the issue is from your question alone.

Comment: I've edit my question body now. that's my code. please help me. This code is working to share all social media. But not working like button and comment (FB). Also Print button

Answer (score 1):

This is due to the Facebook user auth, unfortunately android webview is not fully compatible with auth systems, an alternative that I use in my webview applications is to use "[Chrome Custom Tabs](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/images/customtab/performance.gif)" to auth access to the system of comments that I use.

In my application when the user clicks on comment, a Google Chrome tab is opened inside my application showing the comments page, when the user is not logged, the chrome auth the user without having to close or minimize my application to open google chrome. Everything is done within my own application.

To start the Chrome Tab when I added an "Intent" to shouldOverrideUrlLoading, below is an example of my code.

```html
 @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        if  (url.contains("#comments")){
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
        CustomTabsIntent.Builder builder = new CustomTabsIntent.Builder();
        builder.build().launchUrl(PostActivity.this, uri);
        return true;
        }
        else {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
        }
    }
```

And in Gradle app:

```
implementation 'androidx.browser:browser:1.3.0-alpha01'
```

My url for comment pages has "#comments" you change to something standard that you have in your comment page URLs or if the facebook comment system is directly on the post page, put something that is standard in the url of your posts to open in the google chrome tab.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Kindly please tell me where this code should be place? Please explain step by step.

Comment: I saw that you use wordpress on your site, for my suggestion to work you must have something that follows a pattern in your URL, in settings> permalinks select "Custom structure" and type: / app-post /% postname% /

Comment: Now in your project in Android studio open the build.gradle (app) and in dependencies add this line:  implementation 'androidx.browser: browser: 1.3.0-alpha01'

Comment: Should do settings on WordPress?

Comment: And to finish, replace the shouldOverrideUrlLoading in WebViewClient in your MainActivity by the shouldOverrideUrlLoading that I posted in the answer above and change this line:   if (url.contains("#comments")){      by     if  (url.contains("/ app-post /")){

Comment: As I mentioned, I use this alternative only on the pages that have a comment system in my application, the others I open in the webview, and it is the URL structure that makes this selection of what opens in the webview and what opens in a Chrome Custom Tab, but if you don't want to change the structure of the post links in your wordpress, you can then open your entire site in a Chrome Custom Tab  change this line: if (url.contains("#comments")){ by if (url.contains("neermai.com")){  that all pages of your website will open directly on the Custom Tab.