# How to make reloading by swipe down for webview in Android studio?

Tags: android-studio, android-webview, loading

M developing a Android App with webview code. When I open the App page is loading Automatically. If user want to reload the page while swipe down to reload the page ? Any easy code for it ?

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution is to use `SwipeRefreshLayout`

The example for XML:

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
> <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
>     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
>     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
>     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>     tools:context=".MainActivity">
>
>     <android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
>         android:id="@+id/swipe"
>         android:layout_width="368dp"
>         android:layout_height="0dp"
>         tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
>         tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp">
>
>         <WebView
>             android:id="@+id/webView"
>             android:layout_width="match_parent"
>             android:layout_height="match_parent"
>             tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
>             tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp" />
>
>     </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
>
> </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
> ```

The example for activity:

```
import android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout; 
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity; 
import android.os.Bundle; 
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient; 
import android.webkit.WebView; 
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    WebView webView;
    SwipeRefreshLayout swipe;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    swipe = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.swipe);
    swipe.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRefresh() {
            LoadWeb();
        }
    });

    LoadWeb();
}

public void LoadWeb(){
    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
    webView.loadUrl("https://stackoverflow.com");
    swipe.setRefreshing(true);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode,
                                    String description, String failingUrl) {
            webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/error.html");
        }
        public  void  onPageFinished(WebView view, String url){
            swipe.setRefreshing(false);
        }
    });

    webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int newProgress) {

            if(webView.getProgress()== 100){
                swipe.setRefreshing(false);
            } else {
                swipe.setRefreshing(true);
            }
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed(){

    if (webView.canGoBack()){
        webView.goBack();
    }else {
        finish();
    }
}

}
```

Happy Coding

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I will share my code on this link. If possible please kindly explain where I should place your code and exactly what is the code for reload. https://stackoverflow.com/q/60143729/12854586

Comment: Please explain.. how to do that ?

Comment: Activity_main.xml

Please check here - https://stackoverflow.com/q/60143729/12854586

Comment: You can match our code, It's already similar, you only need to add SwipeRefreshLayout in your XML first, and import in Java